# How to add an environment variable in the package.json file in the dependency section?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, environment-variables, package.json

Currently I have an environment where we are using a shared repo as part of our dependency in our package.json file. I'm trying to inject a environment variable so I can build based on a specific branch.

Currently I have this.
"module": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.com/repo.git#develop"

But was wondering if I can do something like this:
"module": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.com/repo.git#process.env.BRANCH"

I have declared a global environment variable in node, but can't find a way to have it read the environment variable. Just wondering if this is even possible. Thank you

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't include variables in the `dependencies` section.of _package.json_

Comment: Thanks for the update.